# How can I get the Items in a DataGrid into a List<T> or some other collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a Datagrid full of custom objects. These objects have a DateTime property called CurrentTime.

I want to get the value of the most recent CurrentTime into a DateTime object. How can I get a list of the DataGrid items sorted by CurrentTime?

Something like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjs = DataGrid.Items.ToList();
myObjs.SortBy(CurrentTime);
DateTime latestTime = myObjs[0].CurrentTime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your are looking for [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = DataGrid.Items.OfType<yourType>().OrderBy(q => q.CurrentTime).ToList();
```

**yourType** is type of your objects that have a DateTime property called CurrentTime.

Comment: I don't think that any of this methods (OfType, OrderBy, ToList) could increase the number of entries. Unfortunately, I did not see your code and cannot say what causes such behavior. I would recommend you to divide this line to three separate lines and debug it. So, you could find after what operation (DataGrid.Items, OfType, OrderBy, ToList) amount is incorrect. Please feel free to write additional comments, and I'll try to help you

Comment: Sorry, I tried to delete my comment quickly. I had other code that was inserting items into the datagrid twice. I have fixed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's OK. Good luck at your job =)

Answer (score 1):

```
myObjs.OrderBy(x=>x.CurrentTime);
```

Using OrderBy method, sort the Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this expression:

```
DateTime latestTime = DataGrid.Items
                              .OfType<MyObject>()
                              .OrderBy(x=>x.CurrentTime)
                              .First()
                              .CurrentTime;
```

Comment: This almost worked. Your code gets me the correct MyObject, and from there I can get the CurrentTime.

Comment: Sorry, I have just added the last action (gets needed property from our object) to this expression.
But I recomend using FirstOrDefault() instead of First() because if there are no items in your DataGrid.Items collection you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
 var list = myObjs.OrderBy(x => x.CurrentTime).ToList();
```